# How to use grid-template-areas in SASS

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, css-grid

```
 .nevigate-page
     display: grid
     grid-template-areas: 'navigation-icon arrow-left' 
                          'navigation-text arrow-left'
     gap: 1.25rem
 .nevigation-icon
         grid-area: nevigation-icon
 .nevigation-text
         grid-area: nevigation-text
 .arrow-left
         grid-area: arrow-left
```

// Above code is not working & getting below error

[plugin:vite:css] [sass] Expected identifier.
╷
116 │                 grid-template-areas: 'navigation-icon arrow-left'
│                                                                   ^
╵
src\pages\NotFound\index.sass 116:67  root stylesheet

I want icon & text at left side & arrow-left at right side

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you haven't set it up to use SASS but SCSS, there is a big difference in syntax possibilities between the two. So two options

1. Set up SASS correctly
2. Change to use proper CSS syntax (recommended)

css syntax

```
.nevigate-page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'navigation-icon arrow-left'
    'navigation-text arrow-left';
  gap: 1.25rem;
}

.nevigation-icon {
  grid-area: navigation-icon;
}

.nevigation-text {
  grid-area: navigation-text;
}

.arrow-left {
  grid-area: arrow-left;
}
```